# Check if Object fields already exists in another instance

Tags: java

I'm creating multiple instances of the same object and I want to check two fields to know if it has duplicates.

```
public class Professor {
    String name;
    String surName;
    String department;

    // Contructors, Setter and Getters
}

public class DProf {
    String depName;
    private static List<Professor> professors = new ArrayList<>();

    // Contructors, Setter and Getters

    public void addProfessor(Professor professor) {
        if (containsName(professor.name) && containsSurName(professor.surName)) {
            return;
        } else {
            professors.add(professor);
            new Professor(professor);
        }
    }

    public boolean containsName(final String name) {
        return professors.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getName().equals(name));
    }

    public boolean containsSurName(final String surName) {
        return professors.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getSurName().equals(surName));
    }
}
```

Edit: current approach with Professors being stored in `List<Professors>` and two methods cheking if namd and surname exist

Comment: Where do you have the other instances stored?

Comment: You have to override the equals method to check if two instances are same.

Comment: In memory I suppose, should I store them somewhere else?

Comment: @Rancio Where "in memory"? Do you have a Collection somewhere where you store the `Professor` instances? Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do or what the problem is.

Comment: Where do you store them in your java programm? A List? An Array? some custom collection class you wrote? Are they just referenced in other classes? If no reference to the Professor objects exists in your java code the Garbage Collector will delete eventually delete those objects, so your answer "in memory" doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `DProf` class also contains a `List` of `Professor`s.

Interface `java.util.List` declares method [contains(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-). The method returns **true** if the method argument equals one of the objects in the list. Method [equals(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), in class `java.lang.Object` is used to determine whether two objects are equal. Since all classes in java extend class `Object`, that means that your `Professor` class inherits that method. The implementation of method `equals(Object)` in class `Object` is a generic implementation and therefore not suitable for your `Professor` class. Hence you need to override method `equals(Object)` in class `Professor`.

Here is my modified version of class `Professor`.

```java
public class Professor {
    private String name;
    private String surName;
    private String department;

    public Professor(String name, String surName) {
        this(name, surName, null);
    }

    public Professor(String name, String surName, String department) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surName = surName;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String dept) {
        department = dept;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean areEqual = false;
        if (obj instanceof Professor) {
            Professor other = (Professor) obj;
            areEqual = name.equals(other.name) &&  surName.equals(other.surName);
        }
        return areEqual;
    }
}
```

As you requested, method `equals()`, in class `Professor`, returns **true** if both `Professor` instances have the same `name` and `surName`.

Since the code in your question is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I made some assumptions regarding the code. Here is my modified version of your `DProf` class. See notes after the code.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class DProf {
    private List<Professor> professors;
    String depName;

    public DProf(String name) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name, "Null department name");
        depName = name;
        professors = new ArrayList<Professor>(); // create an empty list of professors
    }

    public void addProfessor(Professor professor) {
        // Here I want to check if new Professor instance name and surname already exist in another instance of the object
        if (!professors.contains(professor)) {
            professor.setDepartment(depName);
            professors.add(professor);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DProf magic = new DProf("Sorcery");
        Professor prof = new Professor("Cuthbert", "Binns");
        magic.addProfessor(prof);
        prof = new Professor("Charity", "Burbage");
        magic.addProfessor(prof);
        prof = new Professor("Albus", "Dumbledore");
        magic.addProfessor(prof);
    }
}
```

I added a member `professors` since I assume that a department has a number of different professors associated with it. I assume that initially, a professor is not associated with a department until you call the `addProfessor()` method. Hence I also set the Professor's department in the `addProfessor()` method. I also added a `main()` method simply to allow me to test run the code to make sure it runs successfully.

Comment: Edited post to be more accurate

Comment: It work out, thanks, overriding equals works wonders simplyfing code

Answer (score 1):

you can make a static private field like this :

```
private static list<String> field = new ArrayList();
```

and before you add a Professor  you can check `field.contains(name)`

but i think some better pattern must exist

edit: and add the name in your list when you call the constructor of Professor

Comment: And how could I clear the ArrayList when is the 1st call? I want to do it inside class, right now I made a method to check if name or surname exists in list.

Comment: @ Rancio: "And how could I clear the ArrayList when is the 1st call?" <- What do you mean? The List is initialized as an empty list, so why would it be anything other then an empty list after initialization?

Comment: `new ArrayList();` should be `new ArrayList<>();`. You should never use Raw types without a very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `equals()` method in *Professor* class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Professor professor = (Professor) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, professor.name) &&
            Objects.equals(surName, professor.surName) &&
            Objects.equals(department, professor.department);
}
```

Then you could initialize a *List* inside *DProf* class and add each Professor object you create inside it.

```
class DProf {
    static List<Professor> profList = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean addProfessor(Professor professor) {
        for (Professor someProf : profList) {
            if (professor.equals(someProf)) return false;
        }
        profList.add(professor);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This way you could check whether each Professor object matches with already existing objects.